# unable to use webdriver with chromedriver-helper or webdrivers gems

Tags: ruby, selenium-chromedriver, rbenv

For ruby 2.6.2

webdriver gem is giving this error:

```
... connect_until_stable':  
unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9515 
(Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
```

If I switch back to using the (deprecated) `chromedriver-helper` gem instead of the newer `webdrivers` gem I get a different error:

```
session not created:  
This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 75   
(Selenium::WebDriver::Error::SessionNotCreatedError)
```

even though I have

```
$ chromedriver -v
ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.8
```

I've also tried ruby version `2.4.0`, `2.4.1`, `2.4.2`, `2.5.0`, `2.5.1`, bundling each time and setting the `.ruby-version` file within the project and they all seem to have different issues in using the `webdrivers` or `chromedriver-helper` gems.
Note that I am using rbenv and had to do

```
cd ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
git pull
```

to get make the newer versions available to me locally

I suspect this will resolve soon but right now it's making it hard to find *any* version combination that actually works today (5/20/2019)